# 'Float' right a column when using display: table?

Tags: css

Im using display table for a 3 column section of my site. Im doing this as I need to vertically center the content of the first column.

How can I move the third column to the right while still keeping its text left aligned?

[image]

```
<span class="cont">
  <span class="one">One</span>
  <span class="two">One</span>
  <span class="three">
    <div class="a">Some text and A</div>
    <div class="b">Some more text and B</div>
  </span>
</span>

.cont {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}
.one,
.two,
.three {
  display: table-cell;
}
.one {
  background: grey;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.two {
  background: green;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azbmrP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple solution is to use `float: right` to `.three` class and `vertical-align: top` to `.two` class:

```css
.cont {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}
.one,
.two,
.three {
  display: table-cell;
}
.one {
  background: grey;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.two {
  background: green;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.three {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<span class="cont">
  <span class="one">One</span>
<span class="two">One</span>
<span class="three">
    <div class="a">Some text and A</div>
    <div class="b">Some more text and B</div>
  </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
.three
{
  float:right;

}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raNMXr

Comment: This one doesn't work as OP wants. Cell two lose vertical-align.

Comment: hehe, yes it is that simple :P @AlexChar why not?

Answer (score 1):

```
.table { display: table; margin-left: auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JojRgz)

```
<span class="cont">
  <span class="one">One</span>
  <span class="two">One</span>
  <span class="three">
    <div class="set">
    <div class="a">Some text and A</div>
    <div class="b">Some more text and B</div>
    </div>
  </span>
</span>

.set{ float:right;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
.three > div {
```

float: right;
}

and you can put a `<br>`tag after first div.

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/7081odd1/